# How to read HTML <table> and sort the table content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, html-table

I have a html table with three columns [Title, Category, Sub-Category] and multiple rows . And I want to read the entire table content and make it categorized as below output.

My `<html>` table content is like this.

```
Title   Category  Sub
T1         C1     S1
T2         C2     S2
T3         C2     S3
T3         C1     S1
T2         C1     S3
T1         C2     S3
```

Here is the output format what I really need. I just want to print the above html table content in the below out put format.

```
T1 :
   C1 : S1
   C2 : S3
T2 :
   C2 : S2
   C1 : S3
T3 :
   C2 : S3
   C1 : S3



[Title]
     [Category] :[Sub-Category]
```

Please help me.

Comment: You will need to use AJAX to make a request from a server-side script, like PHP, that can connect with the database and return the results. There are many tutorials on the web for this.

Comment: Wait is this a <table> or something else?

Comment: Sounds like you are wanting a table that has a parent / child relationship.   Give this a try  http://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Comment: What's the code of the `<table>`?

Comment: Here I'm using html and java script only. And i don't want to use any other language.

Comment: Its a html table <table>

Comment: Sounds like a job for associative arrays.

Comment: @JRulle ya right. I need that.

Comment: @rolind, check my answer below using associative arrays. I included a [JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/bpk4e0pe/) to show you that it outputs your desired formatting as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using associative arrays in javascript/jQuery: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/bpk4e0pe/)

```
var tableRowArray = $('table tr');
var titleArray = [];
var mainArray = {};
// build an associative array of the values int he table
tableRowArray.each(function(){
    if($(this).children('th').length == 0) {
        var tempTitle = $(this).children('td').eq(0).text();
        if(mainArray[tempTitle]){
            mainArray[tempTitle][$(this).children('td').eq(1).text()] = $(this).children('td').eq(2).text();
        }
        else {
            titleArray.push(tempTitle);
            mainArray[tempTitle] = {};
            mainArray[tempTitle][$(this).children('td').eq(1).text()] = $(this).children('td').eq(2).text();
        }
    }
});
// print the formatted associative array to the page
$('body').append("<p></p>");
var formattedString = "";
$.each(titleArray, function(index, value){
    formattedString += "<b>" + value + " : </b><br/>";
    for(var key in mainArray[value]) {
        formattedString += "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + key + " : " + mainArray[value][key] + "<br/>";
    }
});
$('p').html(formattedString);
```

Basically, we create an associative array from your table and then the next piece iterates through the array to print it in the format you specified (you may need to edit the set up of the array if you table structure varies from what I used the in JSfiddle).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the table has this code:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Sub</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>T1</th>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>S1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>T2</th>
            <td>C2</td>
            <td>S2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>T3</th>
            <td>C2</td>
            <td>S3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>T3</th>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>S1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>T2</th>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>S3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>T1</th>
            <td>C2</td>
            <td>S3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

We can use jQuery to get output like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("table").hide();
    $("body").append("<textarea></textarea>");
    var s = "";
    $("tbody tr").each(function(){
        s += $(this).find("th").html() + ":\n";
        s += $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").html() + ": " + $(this).find("td:nth-child(3)").html() + "\n\n";
    });
    $("textarea").val(s);
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/9ueervw4/

---

The below code, you get a JavaScript object which is associative!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("table").hide();
    $("body").append("<textarea></textarea>");
    var s = {};
    $("tbody tr").each(function(){
        if (!s[$(this).find("th").html()])
            s[$(this).find("th").html()] = [];
        s[$(this).find("th").html()].push($(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").html() + ": " + $(this).find("td:nth-child(3)").html());
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your consideration. But I want result like what i printed above.

Comment: Title should print once and all the category and sub category should present under the title.

Comment: Yeah, the JSON object does it. :)

Answer (score 0):

The below example will give you the output you want.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var outputtemp = "<table>";
            $("#tbl1 tr").not("tr th").each(function () {
                outputtemp += "<tr>"
                var i = 0;
                $(this).find("td").each(function () {
                    if (i == 0)
                        outputtemp += "<td>" + $(this).text() + ":</td></tr><tr>";
                    else if (i == 1)
                        outputtemp += "<td></td><td>" + $(this).text() + ":</td>";
                    else
                        outputtemp += "<td>" + $(this).text() + "</td>";
                    i++;
                });
                outputtemp += "</tr>"
            });
            outputtemp += "</table>"
            $(".output").html(outputtemp);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="tbl1">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Title
            </th>
            <th>
                Category
            </th>
            <th>
                Sub
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                T1
            </td>
            <td>
                C1
            </td>
            <td>
                S1
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                T2
            </td>
            <td>
                C2
            </td>
            <td>
                S2
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                T3
            </td>
            <td>
                C3
            </td>
            <td>
                S3
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="output">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

Get the data using `getElementbyId` and then you may apply any operation on that data when you have whole data in js variables.